# Как сделать подобие сканера?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как можно реализовать "сканер", как на этом примере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сайт: http://verstka.test30.ru/sklif/personal-office-scanner.html

Здесь это реализовано на `canvas`, но на его изучение сейчас уйдет много времени. Никогда с этим не работал. Может, кто-то встречал подобное на jQuery? Не знаю, с какой стороны подступиться. Подскажите, как реализовать или хоть наводку дайте.

Comment: Извините, но ваш вопрос некорректно задан и не несет смысловой нагрузки, попробуйте перефразровать его

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант, постарался сделать как можно проще:

```js
$("body").mousemove(function(event) {
  x = event.pageX - 50;
  y = event.pageY - 50;
  $('.scaner').css({
    transform: "translate("+x+"px, " + y + 'px)'
  });
$('.scaner .image2').css({
    transform: "translate("+(-x)+"px, " + (-y) + 'px)'
  });
})
```

```css
.image1 {
  position: absolute;
}
.scaner {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px
}
.image2 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=image1>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any">
</div>
<div class=scaner>
  <div class=image2>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/arch">
  </div>
</div>
```